# What do nested "touching" blocks do?

Tags: mit-scratch

Making a Scratch platformer, I discovered that this did **not** work how I wanted:

[image]

...because it just didn't seem to run at the right rhythm for my program.

However, this **did** work:

[image]

...and I notice it being used in platformers such as Sushi Platformer.

Does anyone know **what these nested touching blocks actually do?**

**Update:**

@towerofnix is right... I made an experimental project, at https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/118349555/#player

...with the following experimental options:

[image]

**Results:**

Control: Platform detection works, but jitters up and down too much

Experiment1 (per @towerofnix): works, no jittering!

Experiment2: doesn't work, penguin goes down through floor sometimes

Experiment3: works, because it's equivalent to Experiment1!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scratch isn't magic. It's a normal code interpreter (as far as I know).

Now that that's out of the way, let's be the interpreter™ and figure this out.

1. touching-color will return true or false.
2. touching then takes the input true or false.
3. [touching will go through all sprites named true or false.](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-flash/blob/5cff62b909856b7d7b3d116a5dcc2b4f03de8482/src/primitives/SensingPrims.as#L97)
4. since there are no sprites with those names (at least not in sushi platformer), just continue.
5. [next is `return false`, so return false.](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-flash/blob/5cff62b909856b7d7b3d116a5dcc2b4f03de8482/src/primitives/SensingPrims.as#L101)
6. therefore the nest will always return false.
7. not takes the input false, so it returns true.
8. thus this - [image] - is unnecessary and can be replaced with this - [image]

So if doing that last step doesn't result the same as not doing the last step, we really need to see your project!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something special here...

You want to stop the jittering, you'll have to stop the gravity. Set a condition on the gravity so that it stops whenever your sprite touches the platform. Then, have gravity reactivate on your jump button. The way this is now, it touches the platform, jumps up (a tiny bit), and then touches the platform again. You need to change the way your gravity works.

Comment: That doesn't work because you need to be able to fall off platforms using gravity without jumping.

Comment: If you make it so when you are not touching one of the blocks, gravity is on, then it will work. You will step off, (stop touching) and fall off.

Comment: Yes but gravity moves you down... then you are touching one of the blocks. You need to move up until you're not touching one of the blocks anymore, at which point gravity gets turned back on, which moves you down... this doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid jittering, you can make a block and select "run without screen refresh" and move the entire if [image]